# How can I set up and simulate an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process that depends on the proportional deviations from the steady state?

Tags: simulation, stochastic-calculus, error-tracking

I'm trying to set up a stochastic differential equation and run numerical simulations for the following process:
$$\frac{dV_t}{V_t}=\left[M+\gamma\left(M-\left(\frac{V_t}{V_{t-1}}-1\right)\right)\right]dt+\sigma dW$$

i.e. it's an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process that converges to a steady-state growth rate $M$, with a speed of adjustment $\gamma$, and where the convergence also depends on how much the point-in-time growth rate has deviated from the steady-state growth rate.

If I use `ItoProcess` to input this, Mathematica seems happy enough.

```
proc = ItoProcess[ 
   \[DifferentialD]V[t]/V[t] == 
   (M + \[Gamma]*(M - (V[t]/V[t - 1] - 1)))*
   \[DifferentialD]t 
   + \[Sigma]*\[DifferentialD]w[t], 
   V[t], {V, Subscript[V, 0]}, t, Distributed[w, WienerProcess[]]
   ]
```

However, I am stuck when I then try and generate some simulations, using `RandomFunction`.
E.g. say, I set $M=0.05$, $\gamma=0.5$ and $\sigma = 0.02$, and initial value $V_0$ as 100.

```
M = 0.05; 
\[Gamma] = 0.5; 
\[Sigma] = 0.02;
Subscript[V, 0] = 100
```

Re-evaluating `proc` with those parameters, I get

```
ItoProcess[{{0. + 
    1.*V[t]*(0.05 + 0.5*(1.05 - (1.*V[t])/V[t][-1 + t]))}, {{0.02*
     V[t]}}, V[t]}, {{V}, {100}}, {t, 0}]
```

If I then try and generate a simulated path using, say,

```
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]
```

I get this error message:

[image]

I'm thinking the reason it's going wrong is that there is no 'history' of $V$ for the point-in-time growth rate to be calculated prior to t=0, and therefore it falls over.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help identify what is going wrong, and what I could do to overcome this.

Thanks!